# Azure web app: Issue accessing extensions

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I currently have a free Azure web application, which I use for development and testing.

I need to install Python, along with some Python libraries, since the web application runs a Python script, however when I try to access the extensions tab, it is greyed out, and I can't click it.

Is this function disabled for the development tier in web apps, or do I have to enable it?

I hope some of you have experienced this issue before, and can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is currently the [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python) option for running Python apps in App Service. The App Service deployment engine automatically activates a virtual environment and runs `pip install -r requirements.txt` for you when you deploy a Git repository, or a zip package with build automation enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question about how to enable extensions. However I found that I was using the SSH, but by swapping to Bash I could execute the `pip install` command and thereby get the necessary libraries.